# Remove selected item from a list

Tags: c#, listbox

I've got a list, the list items are updated in a listBox.

Im using the code below to remove items but that just remove the first item, not the selected one.

```
_List.Items.RemoveAt(0);
```

how can I write a code that makes the selected item removed from the list?

Comment: normally listbox contains SelectedIndex property.. so you can use `_List.Items.RemoveAt(_List.SelectedIndex);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are removing the first item in the list _List.Items.RemoveAt(**0**);

To remove the selected item from the listBox you should do it somewhat like this:

```
if(listBox.SelectedIndex >= 0 && listBox.SelectedIndex < _List.Count)
    _List.Items.RemoveAt(listBox.SelectedIndex);
```

I am asuming here that your listbox is a 1:1 copy of the items in your list